# execute r function from java code

Tags: java, r, file

I have a manipulating dataset function in R script which use a directory as parameter. Let's say as

```
preprocessing1 <- function(directory){
...
...
...
}
```

in `script.R`. Output of this function is a manipulated file. 
I want to read my function (`preprocessing1()`) from Java project which can execute a file too. I want to ask how can I solve this problem?

PS: I am very new in Java. from all of articles that I've read, I have to add third parties such as rJava, I have been success to install it, but I don't know what I have to do next.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: See [here](https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2011/01/01/calling-java-code-from-r/)